# Python, Number of Parameters; Class and Method Behavior

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Forgive me: I don't know Python very well. However, I am proficient in SML and C.

I'm going through the Udacity tutorial (https://www.udacity.com/wiki/cs253/unit_2#submitting-input), and I see this line of code:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],
                         debug=True)
```

I looked at the webapp2 source code (https://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/source/browse/webapp2.py). It seems that the init method is as follows:

```
def __init__(self, routes=None, debug=False, config=None):
```

1. How is that in the Udacity line of code, you can call this method without the "config" parameter? Are you allowed to do this in Python?
2. When you say something like webapp2.WSGIApplication(...)
   , how does it know to instantiate the WSGIApplication class as opposed to, say, a WSGIApplication method (if it were defined in webapp2.py as well)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If a parameter is given a default value in the method or function declaration, as `config` is here, it is optional. The positional arguments when `__init__` is called are assigned in first-come, first-serve order, so when fewer than two arguments are given, `routes` gets the first (in any) and `debug` the second (if present).
2. Classes and functions exist in the same namespace in a module, so you cannot have both a class and a function with the same (fully qualified) name. `webapp2.WSGIApplication` will refer to one, and only one, object.

Answer (score 0):

1. Those values you see in the method definition are defaults for the arguments. So if you omit one, it takes the default instead.
2. What? What do you mean "instantiate the class as opposed to a method"?

Answer (score 0):

1. its [default arguments](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/defaultArgs.html) ... yes they are allowed
2. it wouldnt know what you wanted. it would do whichever came later in the file(webapp2)